# .NET 6 StatusCode Enum's returning same string

Tags: enums, .net-6.0

I've been checking out the `System.Net.HttpStatusCode` enum in .NET 6, and noticed some behavior i can't explain, so looking for some help.

Both `Moved` and `MovedPermanently`'s `.ToString()` output is "Moved". How is that possible? I expected "MovedPermanently" for the latter.

[Here is a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wzVmhY) showing the behavior.

Can someone please explain how this is possible? Is there some enum reference / canonical trickery i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `HttpStatusCode.Moved` and `HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently` share the same value `301`.

```
// https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Primitives/System/Net/HttpStatusCode.cs,31
enum HttpStatusCode
{
    ...
    MovedPermanently = 301,
    Moved = 301,
    ...
}
```

So, `ToString` could be `"Moved"` or `"MovedPermanently"` (I'm not sure this is deterministic)

[Enum.ToString source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Enum.cs,1251)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yep, understand they share the same value.. but which "ToString" gets picked? Are you saying if i have a enum with 3 members, all the same value, that ToString() will randomly return one of the three, no matter which one i choose as the value?

Comment: It is not exactly random (depend on the order members are listed by reflection, and the member returned by a BinarySearch), but it will return the same ToString for the 3 members that have the same value.

Comment: no worries. TIL! thanks :)